# How can I quickly listen to just the beginning and end of multiple MP3s?

Tags: windows, mp3

I have many small MP3 files and want to quickly listen to the beginning and end of each file. For this I was considering splitting each file into 3 parts and merging the beginning and end parts to facilitate a high speed check. How can I do this, or perhaps some other method to best achieve my goal?

Comment: You should at least include some info: OS, what have you already tried, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Slice Audio File Splitter](http://www.nch.com.au/splitter/index.html).

[image]